# Color fade Algorithm

Tags: calculus

Is there an algorithm for color fading? How do I fade from color A to color B. How can I make this mathematical?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your colors are given as triples $(r_1,g_1,b_1)$ and $(r_2,g_2,b_2)$ in the RGB color system, you can fade between them with a simple *linear interpolation*

\begin{align}
r' &= (1-t)\cdot r_1+t\cdot r_2,\\
g' &= (1-t)\cdot g_1+t\cdot g_2,\\
b' &= (1-t)\cdot b_1+t\cdot b_2.\\
\end{align}

This gives a blended color $(r',g',b')$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. For $t=0$ it will give the first color, for $t=1$ the second color.

---

Because you asked for mathematics: you can make this a bit more *mathematically elegant* with writing the colors as vectors

$$ C_1=\begin{pmatrix}r_1\\g_1\\b_1\end{pmatrix}, \qquad C_2=\begin{pmatrix}r_2\\g_2\\b_2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then your blended color is given as the vector $C'(t)=(1-t)\cdot C_1+t\cdot C_2$. This line includes all of the three lines above into a single fomurla.